# Prevent idle disk from spinning up during reboot/halt

Tags: hard-disk

I use hd-idle to ensure that the non-ssd disks in my computer don't annoy with their noise me during normal operations. I only need them from time to to time, so I spin them down directly after boot with

```
/usr/sbin/hd-idle -i 0 -a /dev/sdb -i 60 <REPEAT_FOR_OTHERS>
```

that works perfectly. I do this for four disks.

My problem is that when I reboot/halt the computer the disks spin up. This takes time and also isn't good for the disks, so I would like to prevent this. What I already tried:

- The disks are not mounted anywhere
- Three disks are part of a raid 5 setup. I stop the raid before I run hd-idle
- I tried `echo 1 > /sys/block/$short_dev/device/delete`
  to remove the block device just before reboot, but that spins up the disk

There's nothing to be written to the disk AFAIK. And the computer shuts down immediately once the disks are all up.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Thank you.